# Will Oracle sparc servers operate correctly with non-Oracle issued drives?

Tags: storage, oracle, sparc

I've hunted high and low for the following information;

I'm Currently doing some work on an oracle sparc T5-2 server, this line of work will require me to install some extra drives into the machine. I do not have any drives directly from oracle but i do have drives that match the description and specifications of those from oracle.

The drives in question are these = goo.gl/0D7DEt

I just wanted to know if these drives will be compatible with the machine and if it will run correctly. I have asked this question to oracle support but they were unhelpful in answering.

Any links to documentation that back up your answer would be greatly appreciated when building the business case.

Apologies if this question is not allowed, it's my first post.

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: I don't have any Oracle hardware but general server vendors recommend their own drives as those often come with custom firmware for better management as well as the correct hotswap caddies and they get covered by your existing hardware support contracts.

Answer (score 0):

I am SA for several Oracle T4-1 servers.  Our servers were purchased from Oracle with 6 SSDs in each one. We are replacing them with Samsung SSDs.  The Samsung SSDs are warrantied for 10 years (compare to 1 year for Oracle's drives), are more than twice the capacity (256GB, vs. Oracle 92GB), and are about 1/10 the cost.

We installed the first Samsung drives about two months ago, and have had no problems.  Quite happy.